# Prototypical inheritance without prototype?

Tags: javascript, prototypal-inheritance

I think I understand prototypical inheritance in JS but am having trouble writing code to demonstrate a particular idea I have. Consider this extremely simple scenario, where Manager objects derive from Employee objects:

```
function Employee()
{
    this.name = "Axel";
    this.dept = "R&D";
}

function Manager()
{
    Employee.call(this);
    this.reports = ["Report 1", "Report 2", "Report 3"];
}

console.log(new Manager());
```

The output is:

```
Manager {name: "Axel", dept: "R&D", reports: Array[3]}
```

Oddly enough, it seems to me that we've succeeded in demonstrating prototypical inheritance. But the facts that we didn't use `prototype` anywhere disturbs me. Surely the code above isn't the way to do it?

Can someone provide an example that shows the above approach failing?

(By the way, the example comes from the official Mozilla docs, minus the setting of prototypes: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Details_of_the_Object_Model)

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the above approach. In this case you only modify a *single object*, whereas with prototype, you can modify *all objects* with the same prototype.

Comment: @meskobalazs I'm afraid my classically-trained mind doesn't follow. If I write a slew of `new Manager()` wouldn't I get all three properties (name, dept and reports)? As such, it seems to me that __all objects__ further down the road are modified.

Comment: You're not using prototypes or prototypical inheritance at all here. Instead, you are setting properties directly on each individual object.

Comment: Well, I was not precise enough. Later copies of course inherit the values, but when using `prototype`, you change instances of that prototype retroactively.

Comment: @meskobalazs Well, it's beginning to make some sense. So, does that mean the `apply()` line in Mozilla docs (sample here: http://pastebin.com/cH5Dskz9) is misleading?

Comment: One way to think about it: with prototype inheritance, if you modify a property in the prototype, you are in effect modifying that same property in every object with that prototype, even objects that are already created. (Of course if an object has its own property of the same name, that will override the prototype anyway.)

Comment: `.apply()` and `.call()` simply mean "Call a function with a specific `this` value and the provided arguments." They don't create some kind of long-lasting connection between objects or prototypes or anything. It's much more immediate than that. All they do is set a `this` value, set the arguments, and call a function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We've been kicking this around in various comments, but I wanted to give an example that may help clarify things. Starting with your original code:

```
function Employee()
{
    this.name = "Axel";
    this.dept = "R&D";
}

function Manager()
{
    Employee.call(this);
    this.reports = ["Report 1", "Report 2", "Report 3"];
}

console.log(new Manager());
```

We could also do *exactly* the same thing like so:

```
function setEmployee( emp )
{
    emp.name = "Axel";
    emp.dept = "R&D";
}

function Manager()
{
    setEmployee( this );
    this.reports = ["Report 1", "Report 2", "Report 3"];
}

console.log(new Manager());
```

Now we haven't used `.call()` or `.apply()` or anything so fancy. The `Manager` constructor simply calls another function and passes its `this` value directly as an argument. The code does exactly the same thing this way as it did before.

We could take it a step further:

```
function setEmployee( emp )
{
    emp.name = "Axel";
    emp.dept = "R&D";
}

function createManager()
{
    var emp = {};
    setEmployee( emp );
    emp.reports = ["Report 1", "Report 2", "Report 3"];
    return emp;
}

console.log(createManager());
```

Now we're not using constructors, and not even using `this` - we're just creating an object explicitly and passing it around between functions, and the code still does the same thing!

Comment: Thanks for the effort. Yes, it does make things very clear.

Answer (score 3):

```
new Manager() instanceof Manager
> true
new Manager() instanceof Employee
> false
```

Comment: Excellent! At least it's confirmed I was doing nonsense in the name of inheritance. :D

Answer (score 2):

You didn't actually inherit anything. You just "applied" a function on a given object. I think many functional languages can do this.

Inheritance is used, well to inherit, not just apply unrelated functions on a given object.

In your example you're not covering how to inherit methods for instance. Even if you tried to implement method inheritance via a [Proxy](https://en.wikipedia.org/?title=Proxy_pattern) for example this doesn't mean that you inherited the parent.

Comment: Ah! So you mean `name` and `dept` above belong to `Manager` and not `Employee`? If so, how can I confirm this?

Comment: In your example, `name` and `dept` don't "belong" to either `Manager` or `Employee`. They are properties you are setting on each and every individual object, and have nothing to do with the prototypes of `Manager` or `Employee`.

Comment: Put another way, when all is said and done, you have created an object with its own properties that you have explicitly set on the individual object. It makes no difference whether those properties are set in the `Manager` function or the `Employee` function or in some other random function that you call explicitly. In each case they are simply properties of the *individual object*.

Comment: Inheritance means that a new class will behave the same as the new one, without the need to enforce this, ofc you can change the behaviour if you want, but the most gain when using inheritance is that you don't need to and the behaviour that you don't change will remain the same. This is why is called inheritance, because the behaviour is inherited by default

Comment: @dotslash, yes you are changing objects not classes

Comment: you probably don't feel the difference because you're working with object pretty much all the time and the class is just the scaffolding, but if you where to work with classes you'd feel the difference

Comment: @hades2510 I agree with everyone here, except that I still don't have a "proper" JS example yet. Could you point me to a good, simple tutorial?